# Very slow SQL query by adding a JOIN on a specific table

Tags: mysql, sql

First, I'm not really sure if I should post my question here.

I have a simple SQL query with multiple JOIN.

```
SELECT
    ho.id_host AS "ID",
    ho.Hostname AS "Nom",
    CONCAT(COUNT(DISTINCT ip.id_ip), " IP") AS "IP",
    GROUP_CONCAT(ip.IP_Address SEPARATOR ", ") AS "IPList",
    ho.OS,
    ho.Version AS "Version OS",
    CONCAT(COUNT(DISTINCT us.id_user), " utilisateur(s)") AS "Utilisateurs",
    GROUP_CONCAT(us.Nom_user SEPARATOR ", ") AS "UtilisateursList",
    CONCAT(COUNT(DISTINCT co.id_composant), " composant(s)") AS "Composants",
    GROUP_CONCAT(co.Nom_composant SEPARATOR ", ") AS "ComposantsList"
FROM
    Host ho
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    IP ip ON ho.id_host = ip.id_host
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    User us ON ho.id_host = us.id_host
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Composant co ON us.id_user = co.id_user
GROUP BY
    ho.id_host;
```

This query takes 0.250~0.300 seconds to be finished. If I add the last JOIN needed, the query takes 9~12 seconds to be finished. And I don't know why.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Informations inf ON ho.id_host = inf.id_host
```

This last table is one of the smallest in the database with only 172 rows. The ON clause of the JOIN compare two int and not two varchar. If I remove every JOIN except this one, the query takes only 0,072 seconds to be finished.

I wanted to know, why the query takes 10 more seconds to be finished when adding a JOIN to one of the smallest table. In addition, I have some query with more JOIN on bigger tables and they run faster.

**EDIT:** `EXPLAIN` give this:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys |   key   | key_len |       ref       | rows |              Extra              |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 |      SIMPLE |    ho |  ALL |          NULL |    NULL |    NULL |            NULL |  352 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 |      SIMPLE |    ip |  ref |       id_host | id_host |       5 | cmdb.ho.id_host |   11 |                                 |
|  1 |      SIMPLE |    us |  ref |       id_host | id_host |       5 | cmdb.ho.id_host |   32 |                                 |
|  1 |      SIMPLE |    co |  ref |       id_user | id_user |       5 | cmdb.us.id_user |   11 |                                 |
|  1 |      SIMPLE |   inf |  ALL |          NULL |    NULL |    NULL |            NULL |  172 |                                 |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------+------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: Read [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) with care as your query used GROUP BY in a way which is generally not the way to use GROUP BY in RDMS ... You are trusting on a feature which is called functional dependency which only can be tusted on MySQL 5.7.5+ and when sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is active (to force MySQL engine following the ANSI/ISO SQL 1999+ standards rules regrading GROUP BY)  to get correct data, otherwise you risk getting invalid (unrelated) data..

Comment: Query performance related questions invariably require the result of `EXPLAIN ..` plan of the query. If your MySQL version allows, please provide the result of `EXPLAIN format=JSON ...` in the question; if it does not, you can simply run `EXPLAIN ..`

Comment: Please define two indexes (if not done already): `Host(id_host)` and `Informations(id_host)`. Also, at the end of `GROUP BY..` specify `ORDER BY NULL` to avoid filesort (this is a limitation in older MySQL versions, which has been fixed in MySQL 8+)

Comment: `ORDER BY NULL` reduces the time by about ~2 seconds and creating index reduced the total time to ~0.4 seconds. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have the same problem, **@Madhur Bhaiya** and **@Gordon Linoff** help me to reduce the time from 10 seconds to 0,4 seconds.

I've added `ORDER BY NULL` (-2s) and I've created an index on `Informations(id_host)` (-7,6s). The final SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    ho.id_host AS "ID",
    ho.Hostname AS "Nom",
    CONCAT(COUNT(DISTINCT ip.id_ip), " IP") AS "IP",
    GROUP_CONCAT(ip.IP_Address SEPARATOR ", ") AS "IPList",
    ho.OS,
    ho.Version AS "Version OS",
    CONCAT(COUNT(DISTINCT us.id_user), " utilisateur(s)") AS "Utilisateurs",
    GROUP_CONCAT(us.Nom_user SEPARATOR ", ") AS "UtilisateursList",
    CONCAT(COUNT(DISTINCT co.id_composant), " composant(s)") AS "Composants",
    GROUP_CONCAT(co.Nom_composant SEPARATOR ", ") AS "ComposantsList",
    inf.Jumelle,
    inf.Baie
FROM
    Host ho
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    IP ip ON ho.id_host = ip.id_host
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    User us ON ho.id_host = us.id_host
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Composant co ON us.id_user = co.id_user
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Informations inf ON ho.id_host = inf.id_host
GROUP BY
    ho.id_host
ORDER BY
    NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the execution plan.  But based on your description, you probably need an index on the table:

```
create table idx_composant_id_user on composant(id_user)
```

Comment: I think you are right. When I look at the execution plan, the type of `Informations` is `ALL`.